# Using Scrapy to obtain data from HTML datastore

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following code that is attempting to extract data from the first tab of the main table on this page given in the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import csv

filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Football Data\\test" + ".txt"

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    f.write("")
    f.close()

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/705/Archive/Israel-Maccabi-Haifa"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        titles = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        print 'titles:', titles.extract()[0]

        rows = sel.xpath('//table[@id="team-squad-stats-summary-grid"]//tbody//tr')

        for row in rows:

            rank = "".join( row.css('.rank::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            playerregioncode = "".join( row.css('.playerregioncode a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            playername = "".join( row.css('.name::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            realposition = "".join( row.css('.realposition::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            age = "".join( row.css('.age:text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            height = "".join( row.css('.height::text').extract() ).strip() + ','

            mystring = rank + playerregioncode + playername + realposition + age + height + '\n'
            print mystring

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal2'])
```

This is attempting to pull through the data for the first six columns of the first tab. However this is not returning any results. I think this is because all the data is stored further down in the code in the following format (first player listed):

```
DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , [{"TeamId":705,"PlayerId":23608,"Field":{"Value":2,"DisplayName":"Overall"},"IsCurrentPlayer":true,"GameStarted":3,"SubOn":0,"SubOff":0,"Yellow":0,"SecondYellow":0,"Red":0,"Goals":0,"Assists":0,"TotalPasses":140,"AccuratePasses":124,"AerialWon":10,"AerialLost":8,"Rating":7.41,"ManOfTheMatch":0,"TotalTackles":2,"Interceptions":6,"Fouls":5,"OffsidesWon":2,"TotalClearances":40,"WasDribbled":0,"TotalShots":1,"ShotsOnTarget":0,"ShotsBlocked":1,"OwnGoals":0,"KeyPasses":1,"Dribbles":1,"WasFouled":4,"Offsides":2,"Dispossesed":0,"Turnovers":0,"TotalCrosses":0,"AccurateCrosses":0,"TotalLongBalls":27,"AccurateLongBalls":24,"TotalThroughBalls":0,"AccurateThroughBalls":0,"TeamName":"Maccabi Haifa","TeamRegionCode":"il","RegionCode":"il","PositionText":"Defender","PlayedPositionsRaw":"-DC-","Height":184,"Weight":74,"FirstName":"Dekel","LastName":"Keinan","KnownName":null,"WSName":null,"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(464050800000)\/","Ranking":1,"PositionShort":"D(C)","PositionLong":"Defender (Center)","Name":"Dekel Keinan","Age":29},
```

How can I parse this data using Scrapy? I'm not really sure where to begin as I have never come across data stored in this format before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use regex to parse the `DataStore` variable and use the json library to load it into a dictionary.

```
import re
import json

def parse(self, response):

    playerdata = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body).group(1)

    for player in json.loads(playerdata):
        print player['FirstName']
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for replying. that worked great. i've tried amending the code so that it returns multiple fields, such as first name and last name as an example, using print['FirstName', 'LastName'] but this is returning an error. how can i amend your example to return multiple fields? thanks

Comment: `print player['FirstName'], player['LastName']`